# Rendering and Printing RTF in Java

Tags: java, printing, rtf

I've been trying to locate a decent RTF editing and printing solution in java that we can plug into our application.

Looked at the `RTFEditorKit` however it seems to fail at rendering more complicated (and less conforming) RTF documents. 
Also worked a bit with iText but it seems to not support printing. (not to mention support for RTF has been removed in later versions)

Really trying to stick with RTF as that's what our client base is used to, but i'm open to ideas.

Does anybody else do this? How do you do it?

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

See how good [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) (or its successor, [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/)) works with your particular mix of .rtf files.  If OpenOffice/LibreOffice works, then just use it's (Java-ready) API.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the kit to open your RTF
http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html

And this component to print
http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePrinter.html